# Can't find name of specific probability formula, very similar to geometric distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm not exactly attempting to answer a textbook or school question, this is something I'm attempting to figure out for my own sake - so there isn't a written question to use as an example. I'll do my best to explain.

I am attempting to get an event to occur that has a 3% chance of doing so. It will always be 3%, and it is repeatable. How many times must I do the event to get at least a 75% chance for it to happen at least once?

Again, sorry if this isn't enough, and please tell me what I'd be missing, if anything.

Comment: [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: I did know about that. The problem is that it finds probability from number of trials, when I'm trying to find number of trials from probability.

Comment: The principle should work in the same manner.  There will be a 1 to 1 relationship between $n$ and the computed probability.  In fact, since you are looking for the chance of at least 1 success, that will be the probability of $1$ minus the chance of no success, which is $(0,97)^n$.  So you want $n$ to be the smallest integer such that $\cdots$.  **Take Logarithms.**